# MVC RouteData null in controller when invoked via Unit Test

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

When my controller runs normally, RouteData is populated.  But when I run or debug the tests, RouteData is null.  ASP.NET MVC5.

Controller

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var controller = this.RouteData.Values["controller"];  // null ref exception
        var action = this.RouteData.Values["action"];
        var id = this.RouteData.Values["id"];
        ViewBag.Message = string.Format("{0}::{1} {2}", controller, action, id);
        return View();
    }
```

Test

```
[TestClass]
public class HomeControllerTest
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void Index()
    {
        HomeController controller = new HomeController();
        ViewResult result = controller.Index() as ViewResult;
        Assert.AreEqual(false, string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(result.ViewBag.Message));
    }
```

Is this expected?  Is this because the routing engine is not involved in invoking the controller when the test instantiates it directly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it's expected. The controller relies on a `RequestContext` to get the RouteData and is only "ready" after [created on the mvc pipeline](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.defaultcontrollerfactory.createcontroller%28v=vs.118%29.aspx#M:System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerFactory.CreateController%28System.Web.Routing.RequestContext,System.String%29) and the [controller request begins to execute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.icontroller.execute%28v=vs.118%29.aspx#M:System.Web.Mvc.IController.Execute%28System.Web.Routing.RequestContext%29). This doesn't occur when you simply `new` them up.

What you could do is `new` up the pieces manually (i.e. `ControllerContext`, `RouteData` etc.) or mock them and then set those properties on the Controller to be tested.

Comment: Hey! i ran into the same problem. @Shoe What do u mean by "new up the pieces"?

Comment: @AjayAradhya Something like `new RouteData()` for example.